# valueerror: you also need to provide a phone_code_hash

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone = '+XXXXXXXXXXX'

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone).phone_code_hash


client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
```

How can I pass it on `phone_code_hash` to the check client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

If you do not insert the cache, an error occurs `valueerror: you also need to provide a phone_code_hash.`

Answer (score 2):

The hash must be entered in the fifth entry

```
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone).phone_code_hash

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '), phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
```

I took the answer from here https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/9445d2ba535ed7d214a7e6e68b85e7f3af1a690e/telethon/telegram_client.py#L141-L149